# Getting multiple LIVE values into JavaScript from AJAX/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, sqlsrv

I'm making a web application and I'm trying to make it so when you enter the ID of a provider it automatically outputs them into a span, this is my AJAX/JS call

```
<script>
    function showHint(str) 
    {
        if (str.length == 0)
        { 
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "../include/proveedores.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        console.log(telfValor);
        }
    }
    </script>
<span id="txtHint"></span>
<input id="numa" type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
```

And this is the .php it calls to make the search

```
<?
include('conexion.php');
$conex=conex();
// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$descrip = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "")
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM SAPROV WHERE CodProv LIKE '$q'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conex, $sql);
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    $descrip = $row['Descrip'];
    $telf = $row['Telef'];
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
echo $descrip === "" ? "no suggestion" : $descrip;
?>
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

EDIT: This is to make an AJAX calls to return various values into spans with just 1 AJAX call

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    function showHint(str)
    {
// If there is nothing on the textbox, there is nothing in the spans
        if (str.length === 0)
        {
            $('#Span Name').html("");
            $('#Telephone').html("");
            return;
        }

        $.ajax
        ({
//Here goes the file which contains the SQL call
            url: "../include/proveedores.php",
            data: {'q': str},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
// Here goes the data that goes into the spans
            success: function (data, status, jqXhr)
            {
                $("#Span Name").html(data["Array Name"]);
                $("#Telephone").html(data["Telephone"]);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log("Error response:", jqXhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
// This is the text input that will be sent to your query file
<input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
<span id="Span Name"></span>
<span id="Telephone"></span>
```

proveedores.php:

```
<?
include('conexion.php');
$conex=conex();
// get the q parameter from URL, this is what you have posted
$q = isset($_REQUEST["q"]) ? $_REQUEST["q"] : "";

$descrip = "";

if (isset($q) && $q !== "")
{
// THIS IS PRONE TO SQL INJECTION! USE INTERNALLY!
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM PROVIDERS WHERE CodProv LIKE '$q'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conex, $sql);
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    $Variable = $row['Column Name'];
    $Telf = $row['Telef'];
    $Direc = $row['Direc1'];
}

// This is the array to be encoded to AJAX
$values = array();

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
$values["ArrayName"] = ($Variable === "") ? "no suggestion" : $Variable;
$values["Telephone"] = ($Telf === "") ? "" : $Telf;

// Output the json data
print_r(json_encode($values));
?>
```

Comment: in a... not sure if you missed something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you should use a javascript library like jQuery to handle all the tough AJAX lifting. It will make your life sooo much easier. If you want to use regular javascript, you can return a comma-separated string and then parse each value separated by a comma but that can get messy. With that being said, you can use jQuery AJAX and return your data in a JSON encoded data object.

***.php***

```
<?
include('conexion.php');
$conex=conex();
// get the q parameter from URL
$q = isset($_REQUEST["q"]) ? $_REQUEST["q"] : "";

$descrip = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "")
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM SAPROV WHERE CodProv LIKE '$q'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conex, $sql);
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    $descrip = $row['Descrip'];
    $telf = $row['Telef'];
}

$values = array();

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
// NOTE: we're using the same "txtHint" here for the key as we do in the javascript function
$values["txtHint"] = ($descrip === "") ? "no suggestion" : $descrip;
// Set these to something useful
$values["txtPhone"] = "";
$values["txtAddress"] = "";

// Output the json data
print_r(json_encode($values));
?>
```

Now, for the jQuery implementation. The first thing you'll have to do is download the jQuery library from [jQuery's website](http://jquery.com/download/). I would recommend getting the most recent version (currently jQuery 2.x).

***.html***

```
<script src="/script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function showHint(str) {
        if (str.length === 0) {
            $('#txtHint').html(""); 
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "../include/proveedores.php",
            data: {'q': str},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data, status, jqXhr) {
                $("#txtHint").html(data["txtHint"]);
                // You can do this same thing for the other data returned
                $("#txtPhone").html(data["txtPhone"]);
                $("#txtAddress").html(data["txtAddress"]);

            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error response:", jqXhr.responseText);
            }
        });

        // Not sure where this is defined. It might throw an error
        console.log(telfValor);
    }
</script>
<span id="txtHint"></span>
<span id="txtPhone"></span>
<span id="txtAddress"></span>
<input id="numa" type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
```

The obvious change is the call to `$.ajax()` instead of using the `XmlHttpRequest()` object. It is in and of itself fairly self-explanatory. One thing I would like to mention is that since we set the "type" to "GET", the key-value pairs in "data" will be appended to the url as a querystring in the form: `"url?key1=value1&key2=value2&etc..."`. So the resulting url, in our case, would be `"../include/proveedores.php?q=[VALUE_OF_STR]"` where [VALUE_OF_STR] is the value of the `str` variable.

The other change worth noting is that jQuery has a very helpful way of selecting elements. If you want to get an element by an ID you can just use the syntax: `$('#txtHint')`.

Where the `'#'` symbol denotes that we're looking for an element based on the ID and `'txtHint'` is the ID of the element you're looking for. You can read more about jQuery selectors in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I have some points

1) I'm actually using a list of providers, and since it's too big, the TR on them call an OnClick that adds and ?id= to the page so I can use a GET to get all the data later

2) It needs to be live, if a user inputs a code and it matches, it needs to fill the spans, descrip needs to go into numa and telf into numb, how do I fill them exactly?

3) It doesn't work :/ what exactly is include('JSON.php');?

Sorry for being such a newbie but I dont have experience with AJAX, JSON

Comment: What version of PHP do you have? `include('JSON.php');` includes the JSON php library which is used to serialize data objects so you can send them back to the browser in a JSON format (which javascript knows how to read). Depending on your version of PHP, you'll have to download JSON.php and then include it in your project

Comment: Also, what exactly is your question? Do you want to know how to get multiple values back from one AJAX call? Or do you want to know how to constantly make AJAX calls to keep your page up to date without refreshing?

Comment: 5.3 since I have to use the SQL SRV plugin for 2008, but I can't find any file named json.php in my php folder

Comment: I just checked with phpinfo and I have JSON 1.2 with PHP 5.3 for Windows, I want to take multiple values each time a matching code is inserted into numa without resreshing, aka live

Comment: And what exactly is it not doing that it should be? "It doesn't work" isn't too helpful.

Comment: You're right, when I input a code from the db, it doesn't do anything, while before, if the code matched it would search for the name of the provider with that code.

Comment: Aww, that's no fun. Try now?

Comment: Darn, I thought 10 was the requirement. How about now?

Comment: Waiting on approval :) ty

Comment: "Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here. See the faq for more information. You have requested talk privileges in this room; please be patient while the room owner processes your request."

Comment: Updated with fixes we discussed in chat